# Instantiating bean using factory pattern in Spring MVC 3

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, factory-pattern

I got Object coming in a `REST web service controller's` web method which is locally initialized.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = "/test",headers="Accept=*/*")
    public @ResponseBody ModelAndView computeDetails(@RequestBody RequestObj reqObj, ModelMap model) {

        System.out.println(reqObj.getcode());

        return new ModelAndView("responsedetails", "object", reqObj);
    }
```

This RequestObj object holds the key `code` to instantiate dependency using factory.

Different codes classes have been defined which implement BaseCode Interface.

How can I use factory method to instantiate particular code class based on code value coming in as BaseCode type in my service bean?

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way -

Make your factory as `ServletContextAware` in a way to get the currentContext. And define getInstance method as

```
WebApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);

ctx.getBean(classNameToBeInstantiated);
```

Define your bean's inheritance in spring context so that Spring injects its dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do in such cases is:

1. inject the factory into the controller using `Spring`'s bean
2. create a method `getBaseCode(String code)` in the factory (please note: `String` here stands for code type, so use the actual code type if not `String`
3. make `getBaseCode` returning the `BaseCode` interface while constructing the real implementation
4. supposing you have an `execute` method in `BaseCode`, use the `getBaseCode` method into the controller to get the real collaborator and then call the `execute` method to perform the actual action

Ignoring the first point (which I think you can easily looking at any Spring tutorial) the factory will be something like

```
public class BaseCodeFactory {
  public BaseCode getBaseCode(String code) {
    if(code.equals("something")) return new ThisBaseCodeImpl();
    else //and so on
  }
}
```

while `computeDetails` becomes similar to:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = "/test",headers="Accept=*/*")
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView computeDetails(@RequestBody RequestObj reqObj, ModelMap model) {
  //...
  factory.getBaseCode(reqObj.getcode()).execute();
  //...
}
```

As a side note, I will not go for names like the one I choose here, I suggest you to look for something more significative in your domain (`BaseCode` has no meaning for example), take this snippets just as a directive.

**Base on OP comment**. If you have `ThisBaseCodeImpl` which makes use of other Spring bean you can

1. annotate it with [`@Configurable`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Configurable.html) so, when you use `new ThisBaseCodeImpl(/*args if you like*/)` its bean are instantiated by Spring. I don't personally like this solution since, in my opinion, it pollutes the code with hidden Spring's bean. On the other hand is quite flexible, since it allows you to manage both runtime constructor arguments and Spring beans
2. add `ThisBaseCodeImpl` to the Spring context and change the factory, so that a collaborator for `ThisBaseCodeImpl` is injected into it.

**1st point** example:

```
@Configurable
public class ThisBaseCodeImpl {
  @Resource
  private Bean bean;
}
```

**2nd point** example:

```
public class BaseCodeFactory {
  @Resource
  ThisBaseCodeImpl thisBaseCodeImpl;

  public BaseCode getBaseCode(String code) {
    if(code.equals("something")) return thisBaseCodeImpl;
    else //and so on
  }
}
```

Comment: yup this is the way but in this case dependency injection for ThisBaseCodeImpl wont be handled by Spring. That's the disadvantage. I did manage to instantiate the bean using WebApplicationContext getbean method. So the dependencies are managed by spring.

Comment: @AmitN, sorry, it was not clear to me you wanted your `BaseCode` implementations to have dependencies managed by Spring. I will update my answer to provide two other possible solutions for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem well, but in general spring dependencies have nothing to do here. Just write custom Factory class and return BaseCode implemetation depending on the reqObj.getcode().

Comment: HI czajek, Problem is this reqObj is not instantiated by spring context its local to this method. How do i pass on this key in this local object to Custom factory class.